# Opening a pdf and reading in tables with python pandas

Tags: python, pdf, pandas

Is it possible to open PDFs and read it in using python pandas or do I have to use the pandas clipboard for this function?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.annytab.com/extract-text-from-pdf-or-image-in-python/ I think that the hOCR as an intermediate format may help a pdf get into pandas.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use tabula
https://blog.chezo.uno/tabula-py-extract-table-from-pdf-into-python-dataframe-6c7acfa5f302

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df = read_pdf('data.pdf')
```

I can see more in the link!

Comment: Wow, it would install a complete JVM as a dependency.

Comment: It returns a list of dfs (dataframes) and not a single df even if there's only one table found. By default, it extracts tables from page 1 of the pdf. You can use pages='all' to extract tables from all pages of that pdf or pages=x, x is the page number of the pdf that you wish to extract the tables from, or pages=[x,y,z], where you are passing a list of page numbers you wish to extract the tables from.

Answer (score 18):

There is a new version of `tabula` called `tabula-py`

```
pip install tabula-py
```

the `.read_pdf` method works just like in the old version, documentation is here:
https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/

Answer (score 9):

I have been doing some tests with **Camelot** (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/), and it works very good in many situations. And you can try to adjust some parameters if the default ones doesn't work.

It's similar to **Tabula**, but it use different algorithms (Tabula use the vector data in the PDF and raster the lines of the table; Camelot uses Hough Transform), so you can try both to find the best one.

Both have a web version, so you can try with some example to decide which is the best one for your application.

Answer (score 8):

In case it is a one-off, you can copy the data from your PDF table into a text file, format it (using search-and-replace, Notepad++ macros, a script), save it as a CSV file and load it into Pandas.

If you need to do this in a scalable way, you might try this product: http://tabula.technology/. I have not used it yet, so I don't know how well it works, but you can explore it if you need it.

Answer (score 5):

this is not possible. PDF is a data format for printing. The table structure is therefor lost. with some luck you can extract the text with *pypdf* and guess the former table columns.

Comment: what about using `pd.read_clipboard()` and manually copying it? Will the table work? I just do not like manually inputting everything in the pdfs by hand

Comment: @ccsv: who fills the clipboard? this program has to guess the structure of the table, with the same problems

Answer (score 3):

Copy the table data from a PDF and paste into an Excel file (which usually gets pasted as a single rather than multiple columns). Then use FlashFill (available in  Excel 2016, not sure about earlier Excel versions) to separate  the data into the columns originally viewed in the PDF. The process  is fast and easy. Then use Pandas to wrangle the Excel data.

Answer (score 0):

I use Tabula library
for install, via:

`pip install tabula-py`

reading several tables inside PDF by link , example:

```
import tabula
df = tabula.io.read_pdf(url, pages='all')
```

then you will get many tables, you can call it by using index, it's like printing element from list, Example:

```
# ex
df[0]
```

more info here - https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/