# Reading a two sides table in pdf with python

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula

I have a pdf document with two sides, which have a table which is continuing.

First side and second side:
[image]

And I want to get it into a dataframe in python. I am running the following lines:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df = read_pdf("C:/.../20191212.pdf", pages=2)
df.head()
```

The problem is the output looks like:
[image]

So the problem is the table is wrong, I would expect the row 0 to be the table headers, and on top the text in the first header should already be into rows and columns.

How can I fix this? This post links to [tabula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284759/opening-a-pdf-and-reading-in-tables-with-python-pandas).

Comment: can you please try adding header: None and check `df = read_pdf("C:/.../20191212.pdf", pages=2, pandas_options={'header': None})`

Comment: if you are doing this, this leads to the outocme, that the left above corne is now in cell (0,0), which is also wrong

Comment: @PV8 Did you end up figuring out how to solve this issue? I could use some help with a similar situation.