# Parsing a PDF file - I need the escape characters as delimiters

Tags: python, excel, pdf

(Using Python 3.6 on Windows 10)

I have about 1000 small PDF files that needs to be read with python. The expected output of the files are rows of data to be placed into a spreadsheet (or dataframe).

When I open afile using PyPDF2, it successfully extracts all of the actual readable text. But the only way I can think to parse/delimit this file is by utilizing the `\t and \n` escape characters to separate rows and values. Each of values have arbitrary formatting, so I cant delimit on anything else it seems. So what I *think* I need to do is open the PDF file in such a way that the escape characters are present. That seems to be all I need.

What the data looks like:

```
value1    value2    value3    value4
value5    value6    value7    value8
```

What I need it to look like:

```
value1\tvalue2\tvalue3\tvalue4\nvalue5\tvalue6\tvalue7value8
```

Another way I was able to get the data from the PDF file was by opening it in the webbrowser, then having python copy and paste all the text by programmatically doing `CTRL+A; CTRL+C; SaveClipboardContentsToFile()` When I did it this way, the escape characters were included, but now I need to read in the files, instead of just viewing them.

Is there a reliable way of including the escape characters while reading the file? Im hoping for something relatively simple, like `pdf = library.pdf_read(filename, include_characters='escape')`

Ive also tried other various libraries, but there seems to be many of them. And several of the ones i've tried are having issues with installation, let alone usage. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you tried pdfminer.six? https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284759/opening-a-pdf-and-reading-in-tables-with-python-pandas

Comment: ive been trying to use tabula but adding java to my path, for some reason, is like pulling teeth. the location to my java installation is C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe which i pasted directly into my System Environment Variables but its still not working.