# Python Dash Upload Pdf text extract

Tags: python, plotly-dash, decode

My problem is that I like to know what I have to do for take de text from pdf upload using Dash Upload component.

The problem is that I don't like to ask the folder path, I need to take file content, decode to one string and use this.
I don't need a table, I need the texts. I need to extract information of the text.

I see the documentation (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload) but I dont understand how

```
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
```

this is working.

I would like to make this for pdf :

```
if 'csv' in filename:
        df = pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    elif 'xls' in filename:
        df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
```

But I try to make the same conversion that have in csv and xls examples and I take the error:
"utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xe2 ..."
I try decode with too much other formats but does not work

Comment: This post might help [Opening a pdf and reading in tables with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23284759/2529954).

Comment: I've no direct experience, but the tabula-py package is recommended on several sites for reading tables 'trapped' in a PDF. e.g. see https://www.dunderdata.com/blog/read-trapped-tables-within-pdfs-as-pandas-dataframes

Comment: I don't need a table, I need the texts. I need to extract information of the text.